# python: local variable 'subnum1' referenced before assignment. My code doesn't reflect this

Tags: python

My code:

```py
j=0
for j in range(len(str((calcnum1)))):
    if str(calcnum1)[j] == '.':
      subnum1 = str(calcnum1)[:j+3]
      break
    else:
      pass

  print(confirmed,'(+',subnum1 + '%)')
```

What this does:

- calcnum1 is a number that has come out of a calculation. It has many decimal places and I am rounding it to 2 d.p.
- subnum1 is meant to be the number with 2 d.p.
- the program prints out a number (confirmed), then the percentage increase.

Problem:

*When I run it, it doesn't like the line `print(confirmed,'(+',subnum1 + '%)')`*

Error Message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'subnum1' referenced before assignment
```

What is happening here?
Please note: `subnum1` is not referenced at any other time in the code.

Comment: It is likely that the subnum1 assignment statement is not being reached. Can you provide a sample value for calcnum1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round a number to 2 decimal places

```
x = 1.2345678
x_str = "%.2f" % x
print(x_str)
```

will print 1.23

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the first char in the string `str(calcnum1)` is not `'.'`.

Thus, at the first iteration of the loop the if block is not executed and thus `subnum1` is not being defined (or assigned) and so the error when you try to reference it during the printing.

Try to define subnum outside of the loop (in place of that j=0 which can be omitted at the beginning of your snippet) something like`subnum1 = 'not defined yet'`.